# WSO2 Kuberentes AWS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wso2, kubernetes, wso2-api-manager

Here is the issue I am encountering.
I am trying to deploy the WSO2 API Manager which is open source.

Can find the documenation on how to do this here:
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-artifacts/tree/master/wso2am

Dockerfiles:
https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles/tree/master/wso2am

What I did was take the build the docker images which is required for kuberenetes.
I than take these docker images and deploy them to EC2 Container Service.

I than update the wso2 kuberenetes spec files (controllers) to use the image I pushed to EC2 Container Service.

I then go into kubernetes:
kubernetes-artifacts/wso2am and run "./deploy -d"

It than runs the wait for launch script but it just keeps looping and never "finds" that it is up.

```
root@aw-kubernetes:~/wso2kubernetes/kubernetes-artifacts/wso2am# ./deploy.sh -d
Deploying MySQL Governance DB Service...
service "mysql-govdb" created
Deploying MySQL Governance DB Replication Controller...
replicationcontroller "mysql-govdb" created
Deploying MySQL User DB Service...
service "mysql-userdb" created
Deploying MySQL User DB Replication Controller...
replicationcontroller "mysql-userdb" created
Deploying APIM database Service...
service "mysql-apim-db" created
Deploying APIM database Replication Controller...
replicationcontroller "mysql-apim-db" created
Deploying wso2am api-key-manager Service...
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32013,tcp:32014,tcp:32015) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "wso2am-api-key-manager" created
Deploying wso2am api-store Service...
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32018,tcp:32019) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "wso2am-api-store" created
Deploying wso2am api-publisher Service...
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32016,tcp:32017) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "wso2am-api-publisher" created
Deploying wso2am gateway-manager Service...
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:32005,tcp:32006,tcp:32007,tcp:32008) to serve traffic.

See http://releases.k8s.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls.md for more details.
service "wso2am-gateway-manager" created
Deploying wso2am api-key-manager Replication Controller...
replicationcontroller "wso2am-api-key-manager" created
Waiting wso2am to launch on http://172.20.0.30:32013
.......
```

I tried to comment out the "/wait-until-server-starts.sh" script and have it just start everything. But still not able to access the API Manager.

Could really use some insight on this as I am completely stuck.
I have tried everything I can think of.

If anyone on the WSO2 team or that has done this could help out it would really be appreciated.
My theory right now is maybe this was never tested deploying this to AWS but only to a local setup? but I could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Adding some outputs from kubectl logs etc while it is in the loop waiting for server to come up I see these things:

```
root@aw-kubernetes:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-apim-db-b6b0u            1/1       Running   0          11m
mysql-govdb-0b0ud              1/1       Running   0          11m
mysql-userdb-fimc6             1/1       Running   0          11m
wso2am-api-key-manager-0pse8   1/1       Running   0          11m
```

Also doing a kubectl logs shows that everything started properly:

```
[2016-07-21 18:46:59,049]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 API Manager-1.10.0
[2016-07-21 18:46:59,049]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 34 sec
[2016-07-21 18:46:59,262]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://wso2am-api-key-manager:32014/carbon/
[2016-07-21 18:46:59,262]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://wso2am-api-key-manager:32014/publisher
[2016-07-21 18:46:59,263]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://wso2am-api-key-manager:32014/store
```

Comment: Are you deploying the service in a VPC? And if yes is it getting deployed in a Private subnet or public subnet?

Comment: Yes deploying the cluster using k8, which I have confirmed is working properly by deploying a wordpress/nginx kuberentes setup and I could access those just fine.

"export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash"

Comment: I did not get your comment?

Comment: What do you need more clarity on?

Comment: I am asking is your cluster getting deployed in a AWS Virtual Private Cloud and if yes what is the subnet it is getting deployed is it a Public subnet or a private subnet?

Comment: Have you set up the firewall rules as prompted?

Comment: Yes, all the firewall rules have been setup.

Comment: IS this port open in the firewall 32013?

Comment: Yes, the kubernetes minions security group has all the ports open that are necessary.

Comment: Try updating the AWS Cli version and then run the deployment and see if that goes through?

Answer (score 0):

@Alex This was an issue in WSO2 Kubernetes Artifacts v1.0.0 release. We have fixed this in the master branch [1].

The problem was that the deployment process was trying to verify WSO2 API-M server sockets using private IP addresses of the Kubernetes nodes. We updated the scripts to use the public/external IP address if they are available via the Kubernetes CLI. For this to work, you may need to setup Kubernetes on AWS according to [2].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-artifacts/commit/53cc6979965ebed8800b803bb3454f3b758b8c05
[2] http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/